# List Save Button Directing to Another Page

Tags: 2013

How can I direct the Save Button in the New Form to another link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the RedirectUrl property of SaveButton control in your rendering template.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formcomponent.redirecturl.aspx)

Comment: This will not work with items that have a `DocumentLibrary` basetype. I'm still looking for a workaround to this one.

Comment: can you pls elaborate where will i see the save button control?in my newform.aspx , am not able to see any buttons. but, when my newform opened in UI, it works and gong to allitems.aspx page, am trying to edit the newform.aspx page through SP Designer but am not able to see any buttons.what am i doing wrong?

Comment: please, check the rendering template. http://selingernetwork.com/blog/?p=7