# Redirecting to a new web page after adding a new item in the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, alert, modal-dialog, popup

After clicking "Save" button in the pop-up (for adding a list item), I want to redirect to a page to show them a message "Success" or at least an alert window called "Success"?

How can it be accomplished?

**Update:** 
I added the following button to the pop-up (NewForm.aspx)

```
<input type="button" value="Form Action" name="btnFormAction" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={../../SitePages/success.aspx}')}" />
```

But I am getting the following error,

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

edit NewItem.aspx and EditItem.aspx page in SPD and replace `Save` button to this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" 
onclick="{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={PathOfYourConfirmPage.aspx}')}  " />
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this question: [List Save Button Directing to Another Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67428/list-save-button-directing-to-another-page/67433#67433).

Good way to redirect to custom page after save is to use [RedirectUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formcomponent.redirecturl.aspx)  property of SaveButton control.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know why. I updated the redirecturl property column. But still dont work

Comment: Are you sure that your custom rendering template applied? Also, usually rendering template of new/edit form contains two save button on top and bottom.

Comment: Yes. I did apply custom rendering template

Comment: In my newform.aspx page, am not able to view any button, like save or cancel.I opened list's new form in the  designer.